# Remove jQuery Table When MouseEnter on TD

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have some trouble with my jQuery Code!

```
function handleChange2() {

var table = $('#condition').append($('<table>'));
var data = $(this).val();

table.append($('<td>').text(data));
table.append($('<td>').text('Delete').mousedown(deleteRow));

};

function deleteRow() {

$(this).remove();
//$(this).siblings('td').remove();
//$(this).parent('table').remove();


}
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Codehunter/cL3s2/4/ !

So my issue is to delete the whole table! Not just the 'Delete' field!

As you can see I tried some parent and siblings but failed! each time!

**EDIT :**

So here I have the updated jsfiddle with your suggestions. Whas it what you've meant by adding a 'tr' first!
But it still deletes my 'select' element, what should not be!

http://jsfiddle.net/Codehunter/cL3s2/12/

Comment: You ought to add those table cells to a table row, not directly to the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(this).remove();
```

with

```
$(this).closest("table").remove();
```

Comment: Blazemonger is right, it is a good practice to append <td> elements to <tr> elements first. After which, you append the <tr> elements to the main <table> element.

Comment: I tried something like this but as you maybe can see this deletes also my select table! I want just to delete the row I created!

Comment: I thought that its what you wanted to do based on your question and the title...If you want to delete a row, then you must really add your <td> to a <tr>. After which, you may now call $(this).closest("tr").remove()

Comment: Im srry I wanted to say that it deletes also the select tag (not table) the select tag should still be there. Well I'll still try what you've suggested with the tr. Thx!